# nuxt3 how to call pinia store in composeable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia, nuxt-plugin

Since the nuxt 3.4.0  update the pinia store can no longer be used in composeables.

```
//example composable
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth-store';
const authStore = useAuthStore();

export function doSomethingWithStore() {
  return authStore.checkAuthUser;
}
```

you will now receive the below error

```
getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia? const pinia = createPinia() app.use(pinia) This will fail in production.
```

see stackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/broken-pinia-store-in-composeables?file=composables%2FthisBreaks.js,nuxt.config.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `const authStore = useAuthStore();` declared outside any function like you did is called at some early point of application startup and definitely before Pinia instance is properly initialized inside Vue instance.

Like this it will work:

```
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth-store';

export function doSomethingWithStore() {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  return authStore.checkAuthUser;
}
```

Safe places to do Pinia calls (might not be a complete list):

- from within `<script setup>`
- inline in `<template>` section
- inside `defineNuxtMiddleware`

Answer (score 2):

You wrongly installed the @pinia/nuxt module in `nuxt.config.ts`. The `buildModules` property no longer exists in Nuxt 3, you have to use `modules` instead. (And you can tell by the Typescript error you get):

```js
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // replace buildModules by modules
  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],
});
```

Second point, you also need to call the `useAuthStore` from within the composable function, otherwise it's trying to load the store before pinia actually loaded. It's gonna get called when the file is imported, not when the composable is used.

```
import { useAuthStore } from '~/store/auth-store';

export function doSomethingWithStore() {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  return authStore.checkAuthUser;
}
```

See a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/broken-pinia-store-in-composeables-ndepfk)

Comment: yea sorry forgot to update it,  though that issue is besides the point.  you get the error regardless of how you import modules.  i updated stackblitz to show you

Comment: I tested on stackblitz and got it working, but turns out it's a mix solution between mine and @Ellrohir ;-) I updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to Nuxt or its dev tools, you may have only installed `@pinia/nuxt` **if you have used the dev tools for installation**. It's important to remember that you also need to install `pinia` itself. In case you overlooked this step, make sure to install both `pinia` and `@pinia/nuxt`.

You can do this by running one of the following commands:

```bash
pnpm install -D pinia @pinia/nuxt
# or
yarn add -D pinia @pinia/nuxt
# or
npm install -D pinia @pinia/nuxt
```

link to Pinia docs: https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html#Installation